# fill color with percentage of width

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create 'stars review' component in a vue application. The ratings value ‘overallRating’ is an average value of all ratings, and can be any value from 0.0 to 5.0. Inside the component I wrote

```
<span v-for="(star, index) in maxStars" :key="index">
    <span 
        v-if="(index + 1) === Math.ceil(overallRating) && overallRating % 1 !== 0" 
        :style="{ width: (overallRating % 1).toFixed(2).substring(2) + '%' }" 
        class="icon-grey-star full-rating-star">
    </span>
    <span 
        v-else-if="(index + 1) <= Math.floor(overallRating)" 
        class="icon-grey-star full-rating-star">
    </span>
    <span v-else class="icon-grey-star"></span>
</span>
```

The `maxStars` is set to 5 and `overallRating` can be any decimal value from 0.0 to 5.0. What I'm trying to achieve is if an `overallRating`, say `3.7`, set 3 stars with color from the class `full-rating-star`. And set the `4th` star fill with `70%` color by setting the `width` property. And set the remaning star with grey color using the `icon-grey-star` class.

The css used

```
.span.icon-grey-star{
    color: #ccc;
    &:before{
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
.icon-grey-star:before{
    content: '\e818'
}
.full-rating-star{
    color: red;
}
```

The issue is setting the `width` as percentage is not working. What I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the math, not with the view logic

Comment: Indeed, if you have a 5 star rating why have decimals? Why not 10 stars or 100?

Comment: @Paulie_D Ratings value is an average value between 0 and 5.

Comment: span does not have a width.

Answer (score 2):

This is showing how to do it for all the stars. But you can easily use the background and the clipping for a single star.

```css
:root {
  --rating-max: 5;
  --rating-content: '★★★★★';
  --rating-inactive-color: #CCCCCC;
  --rating-background: #FFDD00;
}

.rating {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.rating::before {
  --rating-percent: calc(var(--rating-value) / var(--rating-max) * 100%);
  content: var(--rating-content);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--rating-background) var(--rating-percent), var(--rating-inactive-color) var(--rating-percent));
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>0</p>
<div class="rating" style="--rating-value: 0.0;"></div>

<p>1</p>
<div class="rating" style="--rating-value: 1.0;"></div>

<p>2.5</p>
<div class="rating" style="--rating-value: 2.5;"></div>

<p>3.3</p>
<div class="rating" style="--rating-value: 3.3;"></div>

<p>5</p>
<div class="rating" style="--rating-value: 5;"></div>
```